# Firmware disassembler for c-sky processor (ck803s)

Tags: firmware-analysis

can you tell me why objdump does not correctly disassemble the firmware for the C-SKY (ck803s) processor? what is .long: between the lines, unknown instructions? or am I setting the parameters for objdump incorrectly? here are mine: ./objdump -D -b binary -m csky:cs803 -EL firmware.bin

[image]

from off. sources use CK803S processor

[image]

this is how the bootloader works

[image]

The firmware is launched from the specified address at offset 0x04, look at the dump merged from the flash drive

[image]

objdump output

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that’s a code segment? I haven’t used objdump for ages, but it does say data at the top not code. Do you know what the entry point for the loaded firmware is?

Comment: There is no 32-bit instruction from the entire dump

Comment: I had an idea to write my own disassembler, but then the first instruction is 0xC001112C, according to the description this is a 32-bit instruction, this is indicated by bits 30 and 31, but I did not find such an instruction in the documentation

Comment: Is it possible to tell objdump that the data and instructions are 32 bit? it even selects the data as 16-bit little-endian

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... post the text instead ... https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: posting the firmware, or at a minimum, more extracts of it might help too.

Comment: @Ian Cook https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_rqy9umHwiZXt2LvSbjiShc0rP7WcCM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: two different devices, but the beginning of the firmware is the same, it seems there is a certain header: i.stack.imgur.com/t4Xow.jpg

Comment: Everything worked out for me and I even corrected the firmware, it really is a c-cky processor

Comment: @Andynvkz Great, glad to hear it! What was the problem in the end? Can you post your own answer to the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole problem is that all versions of objdump and even llvm-objdump incorrectly disassemble 32-bit instructions of C-SKY processors, I managed to find a working objdump version 2.27 on the website https://www.xrvm.cn/ there is also an Eclipse-based IDE

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You've asked multiple questions. I don't know that version of `objdump` enough to comment on whether its a bug or missing option.

However, I can explain how the 32-bit instructions work.

The c-sky instruction stream is a series of 16-bit words.  If bits 15 and 14 of the instruction word are NOT both `1`s then it's a 16-bit instruction.
However, if bits 15 and 14 of the instruction word are both `1`s then it's a 32-bit instruction with the low 16-bits of the instruction in the following word.

Consider a hypothetical instruction with hex coding `C1234567`.

This will be stored as two 16-bit words `C123` and `4567` in that order

In a big-endian environment, this will be stored as the following bytes -

```
C1 23 45 67
```

In a little-endian environment, this will be stored as the following bytes -

```
23 C1 67 45
```

---

In your firmware above the instruction at `3001000` is correct but the following instruction at `3001002` is actually `C0016420`

```
03001000: 112c      lrw     r1, 0x80000100
03001002: c0016420  mtcr    r1, cr<0,0>
```

Writing to control registers is very plausible in boot/init code.

The later 32-bit instruction with .long in the objdump output also seem to make sense.